# How to write a floating point constant

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm not aware and cannot quicly find the right way to enter floating point constant in C++.

If i want 2^-52, what should i write ? And, what does << with float ? 
Is that correct ?

```
const double pres = 1>>52
```

Comment: using unions to shift "mantissa" part of a float is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Answered here(duplicate?)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806581/forms-of-constants-for-high-performance-addition-and-multiplication-for-double/11806593#11806593

Comment: No - that's not a dupe - for constants such as this there a better solutions than unions and bit fiddling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you really want the precision of `double` representation. In this case, don't use magic constants. Instead you can use this:

```
const double pres = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly the constant i need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hex float](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) representation for this:

```
const double pres = 0x1p-52;
```

Comment: Hexadecimal floats are in C, but not in C++, for some reason.

Comment: Oh - that's annoying - I'd never really noticed - presumably g++ and other compilers support this in C++ as an extension ?

Comment: Yes, I believe g++ supports that, but MSVC doesn't.

Comment: This is by far the single most obnoxious omission in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<math.h>
double pres = 1/pow(2,52);
```

Comment: does gcc compute this statically ?

Comment: @Enjolras Chances are, it does. But that’s not guaranteed.