# Streaming string literals in C++

Tags: c++, stl, literals

Let's say that I have some in-house framework for files and streams. I have `IOutputStream` interface class with `write(char const *buffer, size_t size)` and `flush()`. I have a tool, called `Printer` which can be used with any instance of `IOutputStream` descendants. Then I have `Printer & operator<<(T x)` style methods, where `T x` is the data (or a reference or a pointer to it) to be written.

For example `Printer & operator<<(int x)` will translate `x` to string, and will call the referenced output stream's `write(...)` function for real.

Let's see the problem! Invocation: `printer << "appletree";`. It calls `Printer & operator<<(char const *s)`. For this kind of usage, I have to call an `strlen(s)` to determine the size, and after that I can call the final step. This is rather insane since I know the length of `appletree` at compile time.

Are there any good practice for this? How STL's `ostream` plays with titerals?

Comment: Is the call to `strlen` a performance bottleneck? Personally, I would just take the hit of the `strlen` call to keep your code simple to read (assuming it's not a performance hit).

Comment: See this [answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607) which shows that sometimes the compiler will be able to compute `strlen("some text")` at compile time. Just call it, and hope for the best. In your case, I bet the printer will be the bottleneck anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since string literals have type `const char(&)[]`, you could add an overload for them:

```
template<size_t n>
Printer& operator<<(const char (&cstring)[n]) {
    write(cstring, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a reference where the type of string literals is described?

Comment: @Notinlist there you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
template<std::size_t Size>
Printer& operator << (const char (&s)[Size]);
```