# Using memcpy to copy part of an array, and other memory manipulation tools

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

Is it possible to use memcpy to copy part of an array?

Say for example we have an array of 10 integers. Can we create a new array, and copy the last 5 integers into it?

Are there other memory/array copying/manipulation tools which are available for use with c/c++?

Comment: You almost certainly want to use `std::vector` rather than arrays when writing code in C++ (unless you have a really good reason to want a container with a size that is fixed at compile time, in which case you should use `std::array` rather than built in arrays).

Comment: Raw memory is exactly what I need for this purpose: The execution is time critical and must be fast. std::vector will not suffice. (Or at least I assume it will be slower.)

Comment: You assume it will be slower, but vector's performance may surprise you. At least perform timing metrics before you discount the STL altogether.

Comment: `std::vector` will be as fast as possible, assuming you use it right.

Comment: Please check out [my favorite example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607) of compiler optimizations (I wrote it myself :-) before you try to improve on low level operation. The compiler will do that for you. In my example, 10 lines of C++ template code turns into 4-5 machine instructions and executes in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memmove()` serves for this purpose.

EDIT: `memcpy()` works just fine. It is probably more streamline anyway.

In this example, the code would be something like this:

```
int array1[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int array2[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

memmove(array2, array1 + 5 * sizeof(int), 5 * sizeof(int));
```

This will copy 5 lots of `int` from array1, position 5, to array2, position 0.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. `memmove` is identical to `memcopy` except that it correctly handles overlapping source and destination memory ranges. The answer doesn't address when it is possible to copy part of an array using `memcopy`/`memmove`.

Comment: Okay, so in which case memcpy is the answer.

Comment: memcpy is the question. This answer says nothing about what types of arrays can be copied with memcpy.

Comment: `array1 + 5 * sizeof(int)` is a place far away from `&array1[5]`

Comment: Please explain rather than adding nonsense comments.

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to use memcpy to copy part of an array?

No, it is not possible in the general case. You can only do that when the type of the elements in the array is of *trivial* layout.

> Say for example we have an array of 10 integers. Can we create a new array, and copy the last 5 integers into it?

`int`s are *trivial* types, so for that particular case it would work:

```
int source[10] = { ::: };
int target[5];

std::memcpy( target, source + 5, 5 * sizeof(int) );
```

> Are there other memory/array copying/manipulation tools which are available for use with c/c++?

Sure, the entire set of algorithms in *C++ Standard Library* will work with arrays. You use pointers to the first and one-past-the-last elements in the array as `begin/end` iterators. Or if you are using *C++11* then just `std::begin|end( array )`.

```
std::copy( source + 5, source + 10, target + 0 );
```

or

```
std::copy( std::begin(source) + 5, std::end(source), std::begin(target) );
```

---

Here is a metafunction you can use to check whether a type is *trivial*, along with the definition of such concept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial

Comment: @EdwardBird: Yes -- for example, it is impossible to copy objects which do not have copy-constructors.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Yes, any type that is not _trivial_. That includes pretty much every type that is not a plain old C type.

Comment: @EdwardBird it is only guaranteed to work for types that have a trivial constructor, trivial destructor, trivial copy and move constructors and trivial copy and move assignment operators. That means pointers are okay, but smart pointers are not.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Pointers and arrays are both plain C types, so yes. Every fundamental type is trivial, and an aggregate (array or struct) of trivial types is trivial as well. `std::string` and `std::complex` on the other hand are not trivial.

Comment: Basically, it will work for everything if you write your own constructors for copy and assignment?

Comment: @EdwardBird: No, it won't work for anything with a constructor and/or copy-assignment, either explicit or implicit, that is not trivial.

Comment: What about an array of floats? Is there a list somewhere of which types are "trivial"?