# What's the difference between "" and {} for initializing an empty string?

Tags: c++, string, initialization

```
string a = "";
string b = {};
```

I couldn't really find a good reference explaining the difference between them. Does a compiler see them differently? Then, why?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is constructed using copy initialisation.

`b` is constructed using copy list initialisation.

For a `std::string` the compiler will produce the same thing; a zero length string.

But the mechanism by which the string is constructed may well be different - a compiler, conceptually at least, will have to traverse the anonymous temporary const char[] passed to construct a.

For other types there may be differences; research the two terms above for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, no difference.

```
string b = {};
```

initializes the string with the type's default value, which is an empty string.

```
string a = "";
```

initializes the string with a specific value, which happens to also be an empty string.

Note that just doing `string c;` would also create an empty string.

Comment: Actually there could be difference, in the second case compiler may have to call `strlen` or something like that to realize that string is empty. It could be optimized but there is a good chance that it would not.

Comment: @Slava - On the contrary, [there is an extremely high chance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607) that it will be optimized.