# Performance comparison: f(std::string&&) vs f(T&&)

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to understand the performance implications of using `WidgetURef::setName` (`URef` being a Universal Reference, the term coined by Scott Meyers) vs `WidgedRRef::setName` (`RRef` being an R-value Reference):

```
#include <string>

class WidgetURef {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void setName(T&& newName)
    {
        name = std::move(newName);
    }
    private:
        std::string name;
};

class WidgetRRef {
    public:
    void setName(std::string&& newName)
    {
        name = std::move(newName);
    }
    private:
        std::string name;
};

int main() {
    WidgetURef w_uref;
    w_uref.setName("Adela Novak");

    WidgetRRef w_rref;
    w_rref.setName("Adela Novak");
}
```

I do appreciate that with universal references one should be using `std::forward` instead, but this is just an (imperfect) example to highlight the interesting bit.

**Question**
In this particular example, what is the performance implications of using one implementation vs the other? Although `WidgetURef` requires type deduction, it's otherwise identical to `WidgetRRef`, isn't it? At least in this particular scenario, in both cases the argument is an `r-value` reference, so no temporaries are created. Is this reasoning correct?

**Context**
The example was taken from Item25 of Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++" (p. 170). According to the book (provided that my understanding is correct!), the version taking a universal reference `T&&` doesn't require temporary objects and the other one, taking `std::string&&`, does. I don't really see why.

Comment: `std::move`ing from an universal reference doesn't do what you think it does. Use `std::forward` instead.

Comment: Why does Mr. Meyers think it's necessary to coin new terms when the ones in the standard are more than sufficient?

Comment: `std::string` is not the default type of a character array.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think he coined the term long before the standard did so.

Comment: There is more to this than parameter passing. You should also consider inlining, the use of [small string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring), and the actual [cost of constructing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607). Often low-level optimization attempts turn out to be premature.

Comment: That's true, thanks @BoPersson! But in this particular example I'm only really interested in whether a temporary is being created. Sorry, I should've been a bit more clearer about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this particular example, what is the performance implications of using one implementation vs the other?

Universal references, as Scott Meyers calls them, are not primarily there for performance reasons, but, loosely speaking, to treat both L- and Rvalue references in the same manner to avoid countless overloads (and for being able to propagate all type information during forwarding).

> [...] so no temporaries are created. Is this reasoning correct?

Rvalue references do not prevent temporaries from being created. Rvalue references are the kind of references that are able to be bound to temporaries (apart from const lvalue references)! Of course, in your example, there will be temporaries, but the rvalue reference can bind to it. The universal reference first has to undergo the reference collapsing but in the end, the behaviour will be identical in your case:

```
// explicitly created temporary
w_uref.setName(std::string("Adela Novak")); 
// will create temporary of std::string --> uref collapses to rvalue ref
// so is effectively the same as
w_rref.setName("Adela Novak");
```

By using the rvalue reference on the other hand, you force a temporary implicitly as `std::string&&` cannot bind to that literal.

```
w_rref.setName("Adela Novak"); // need conversion
```

So the compiler will create a temporary `std::string` from the literal the rvalue reference then can bind to.

> I don't really see why.

In this case, the template will be resolved to `const char(&)[12]` and thus, no `std::string` temporary will be created in contrast to the case above. This therefore is more efficient.

Comment: No, `w_uref.setName("Adela Novak")` won't create a temporary: it will pass C-style string as an argument and then call `operator=(const char*)`

Comment: @yeputons Never said that, note there is an explicit temporary to illustrate the fact that in this case, Uref and Rvalue ref behave the same.

Comment: Cheers @Jodocus, that's spot on! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

`setName(T&& newName)` with argument `"Adela Novak"` gets T duduced as `const char (&)[12]` which is then assigned to `std::string`.

`setName(std::string&& newName)` with argument `"Adela Novak"` creates a temporary `std::string` object which is then move assigned to `std::string`.

The first one is more efficient here because there is no moving involved.

Comment: [`std::string&&` inlines better](https://godbolt.org/g/eNHgdH). I doubt the moving have much to do with efficiency

Comment: @PasserBy Basically, you claim that `char const(&)[12] -> string -> string` is faster than `char const(&)[12] -> string`, is that right?

Comment: I meant after optimizations, it isn't the deciding factor. Especially considering string moves is likely copying 16 bytes. ([It's not](https://godbolt.org/g/9hNAfK), wow that assembly is horrible)

Comment: Thank you @MaximEgorushkin, once you mentioned what T is being deduced as I immediately realised what was the mistake in my reasoning!

Answer (score 2):

Scott himself says that `WidgetURef` "compiles, but is *bad, bad, bad!*" (verbatim). These two classes behave differently as you use `std::move` instead of `std::forward`: `setName` therefore can modify its argument:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class WidgetURef {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void setName(T&& newName)
    {
        name = std::move(newName);
    }
    private:
        std::string name;
};

int main() {
    WidgetURef w_uref;
    std::string name = "Hello";
    w_uref.setName(name);
    std::cout << "name=" << name << "\n";
}
```

can easily print `name=`, meaning that the value of `name` was changed. And indeed it does on ideone at the very least.

On the other hand, `WidgetRRef` *requires* that the passed argument is a rvalue-reference, so the example above wouldn't compile without explicit `setName(std::move(name))`.

Neither `WidgetURef`, nor `WidgetRRef` require creating extra copies if you pass `std::string` as an argument. However, if you pass something which `std::string` can be assigned from (such as `const char*`), then the first example will pass that by reference and assign it to string (without any copies except for copying data from C-style string into `std::string`), and the second example will first create a temporary `string`, and then pass it as an rvalue reference to the method. These properties preserve if you replace `std::move(newName)` with a correct `std::forward<T>(newName)`.

Comment: Correct usage of `std::forward` with universal references like `T&&` is `std::forward<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arguments as stated in the question

```
template<typename T>
void setName(T&& newName)
{
    name = std::forward<T>(newName);
}
```

Will invoke the `std::string` assignment operator for the data member `name` with a `const char *` argument

```
void setName(std::string&& newName)
{
    name = std::move(newName);
}
```

Invokes `std::string` constructor to create a temporary, to which the Rvalue Ref can bind to.

Invokes `std::string` move assignment / constructor for the data member `name` with a `std::string&&` argument

Invokes `std::string` destructor to destroy the temporary, from which we moved the data.